# Can not define operator on list

Tags: c#, list, entity, operator-keyword

I have an error in this section :
i need + operator for sum two List...

```
public partial class Question
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Question()
    {
        this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
    }

    public long Question_Code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> Question_ExamCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> Question_LessonCode { get; set; }
    public string Question_Text { get; set; }
    public string Question_OrginalLable { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
}
```

then :

```
public class FinalQuestions
{
    public FinalQuestions() { }
    public List<Question> StoreQuestions { get; set; }

    public static List<Question> operator +(List<Question> FQ1, List<Question> FQ2)
    {
        foreach (var item in FQ2)
            FQ1.Add(item);

        return FQ1;
    }
}
```

One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type!!!

Comment: Yes. You're not going to be able to do that, basically. (Your implementation modifies the first operand, which seems like a *really* bad idea too...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet commented, this isn't possible.

The idiomatic way to combine two sequences is to use [Enumerable.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This would let you combine the questions contained in two lists into a third list like so:

```
var all = first.Concat(second).ToList();
```